# TypeScript closures - an "almost" solution

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures

One of my biggest bugbears with TypeScript is the fact that it compiles all methods (regardless of the access modifier) to the prototype.

**Example**

```
class Example {
    public getString(): string {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    private getNumber(): number {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

As we know, the access modifiers are only checked at compilation, thus ignored by the emitted JavaScript. One way JavaScript developers have learned to mitigate this is to use closures (okay, we know there are performance penalties to pay with closures, but I believe there are cases where closures are absolutely necessary).

**Example**

```
var Example = (function () {
    function Example() {
        this.getString = function () {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        var getNumber = function() {
            return 123;
        }
    }

    return Example;
})();
```

The above example respects the public/private access.

I've worked out that by using lambda syntax we can declare public closure methods within TypeScript.

**Example**

```
class Example {
    getString = (): string => {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

It's not particularly pretty, but it works.

**What I would like to know is:** How would I declare private closures in TypeScript?

**Example**

```
class Example {

    // TypeScript doesn't like this!
    var getNumber = (): number => {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

See more on this bugbear here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2940

Comment: This seems like a non-issue to me. You can't use private functions in other classes in typescript, so why does this bug you? Are you trying to hide the functions from JS devs who will investigate the methods of an object in the console? If so, just prefix them with an underscore and if they use those functions then that's their own fault.

Comment: @DavidSherret you've got my point. I guess I come from the classical OOP where you are expected to provide correct levels of access to methods, so that 3rd party devs know exactly what they can/can't do. I wish I could do this cleanly with JavaScript, but the only real solution is to use closures. I don't like the idea of something being private in one language, and then public the moment it compiles. Whilst I understand TypeScript's motivations in this respect, I still see the fact that TypeScript cannot create closure based classes as a limitation.

Comment: @DavidSherret - also, you're right that it's another dev's fault if they use functionality not intended for their use, but I'd rather get the response "You've written a bulletproof API", rather than "Due to the number of leaky abstractions in your API, it's leaking like a sift!"

Comment: I definitely understand the concern if it is a library that will be used by JS devs—to clarify, for typescript devs it's a non-issue. Personally, I think sacrificing code clarity and simplicity is not worth it in order to get over the limitations of JS. Using the [underscore prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties) is for sure not perfect, but to me clean simple code is of higher importance than completely preventing someone from accessing undocumented methods and properties.

Comment: ...JS is just terrible in this regard, but I do agree that it would be nice for typescript to have the option of compiling the code in this way, though that might be a lot of work for them to implement :/

Comment: I've previously had to fix bugs in the Dojo framework for my project's use of it, and wanted to apply my fixes without touching their source code. They placed their private methods usually under underscore-access (ie, _onUnload) so I was able to tweak their functionality. To be fair, in a compiled language like C++ this would be impossible, and might prevent bad changes from happening. Each language seems to come with its own "themes" of development, some good and bad. For instance, the "everything can be changed at runtime with enough hacking" mentality is shared by Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript brings types and accessors to ES6 (and it checks both statically). The `class` keyword in TypeScript is the standard `class` keyword from ES6. There are no private closures in ES6 classes. This syntax is **not** valid in ES6:

```
class Example {
    var v = /* ... */; // invalid in ES6
}
```

If you need to declare a closure that encapsulates variables, you should use the classic JavaScript way. I strongly suggest to takes advantage of the TS interfaces:

```
interface NamedObject {
    getName(): string;
}

let createNamedObject = function (name = 'John'): NamedObject {
    return {
        getName: function () {
            return name;
        }
    };
};

let obj: NamedObject = createNamedObject();
```

---

If you *really want* to make class methods with closures, you can do this:

```
class BadPerformance {
    public getName: () => string;

    constructor(name = 'John') {
        this.getName = () => {
            return name;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, TypeScript supports the class properties proposal - so `v = ...` is valid in TypeScript (no var), in ES this is currently a stage 0 proposal pending TC input.

Comment: @Tarh has the correct answer. Though you should clean it up by setting a local variable `var privateName = name` so that it is clear that this is really private. Then return the `privateName`. There are a few real case scenarios where this should be used. In all others use public methods marked private by typescript. Wrap your entire production build (without a public API) in a clusure at buildtime.

Answer (score 1):

> As we know, the access modifiers are only checked at compilation, thus ignored by the emitted JavaScript.

That's because privacy in this context is privacy of the API from other developer. If you want them to know that the method is private - provide them with a `.d.ts` file so their editor can know that or don't document it in the API Documentation.

In JavaScript the documentation is often regarded as the API.

> What I would like to know is: How would I declare private closures in TypeScript?

You can create functions in the constructor which would declare them on the instance and not on the prototype. This would allow you to use a closure - it also goes against prototypical inheritance and the nature of TypeScript and JavaScript.